# Replacing words with their synonyms in string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This is a very basic example for what im trying to do.

i have this string.

`$text = 'stackoverflow is intelligent';`

after removing stopwords

```
 $stopwords=array(
  'is', 
  'the', 
 );

$text = preg_replace($stopwords, "", $text);`
```

output:

> stackoverflow intelligent

after exploding the string by space

`$text = explode(" ", $text);`

output in array:

> stackoverflow, intelligent

now i have the 2 words

`$text[0]; // stackoverflow`

`$text[1]; // intelligent`

In my sql database i have 3 colums. in the first are the words, in the second her synonym and in the third is the shortest synonym by leng of characters. like this:

```
 word         synonym  shortsynonym

 intelligent  clever   smart
```

This is the hard part of the problem:

First Step is is to check if the `words` from string have a synonym in database
in this case we have to check for

`$text[0]; // stackoverflow`

`$text[1]; // intelligent`

after checking for both we result that `$text[0]; // stackoverflow` dosent have a synonym so we leave as is. and the result for `$text[1]; // intelligent` result positive.

After checking i want to perform a search in database and `replace` in this case the word `intelligent` with her synonym, and `if` the `word` have a `shortest synonym` replace with the `shortest`, `if` the word dosent have a synonym leave as is.

```
 possibility1: output: 'stackoverflow is smart'
 possibility2: output: 'stackoverflow is clever'
 possibility3: output: 'stackoverflow is intelligent'
```

in this case after returning the output will be:

```
 output: `stackoverflow is smart`
```

(Maybe this is not a real question to ask here but any help from you will be greatly appreciated. and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: So what exactly does *not* work?

Comment: So, You want the whole program to acheive this?

Comment: i dont know how to perform the search in database. Step1: check if a word have a synonym, if not leave as is. step2: after checking in step1 and the result is positive do the replacement.

Comment: This is a very basic task. Why don't you read any tutorial? Read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: yes but how to search in db for each word in string after removing stopwords? in the example i do it manually `$text[0];` - word 1 etc...

Comment: Something as simple as `SELECT word,synonym,shortsynonym FROM words WHERE word IN('stackoverflow','intelligent');` should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: The advice from @RocketHazmat should be able to help you along. This question as it stands doesn't really fit SO format.  You might also consider eliminating the preg_match as you have no need for regex here.  Just explode initial string on spaces and `array_diff()` with your stop words.

Answer (score 0):

> After checking i want to perform a search in database and replace in
>   this case the word intelligent with her synonym, and if the word have
>   a shortest synonym replace with the shortest, if the word dosent have
>   a synonym leave as is.

based on the logic you presented above, the appropriate SQL would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
`word`, 
IF(NOT ISNULL(`shortsynonym`), `shortsynonym`, IFNULL(`synonym`, `word`)) as replacement 
FROM words 
WHERE `word` IN ('stackoverflow', 'intelligent')";
```

Have not tested it, but the above ought to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem with the design of the program or with the actual mechanics of writing a query?

If it is design you may want to consider the size of your "thesaurus" if it is small it may make more sense to query your DB at the start of the program and load the result into a key value array. You can then work with the array instead of hitting your db on every request. It should speed up the program too.

If the problem is with writing the sql query you may want to take time out on your project to read some tutorials. I'd recommend PDO PHP 5.4 for your queries, if you learn it it makes writing your queries a cinch.

[PDO PHP API](http://php.net/pdo)